# Analyze logfile from GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi My app had visitors and I like to analyze the log file. Can I run a log analyzer program on the log file that google app engine allows us to download? Are third-party programs such as webalizer and visitors compatible? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Google Analytics on your web app.  If you want to do some sort of server-side visitor analaytics (instead of the client-side Javascript that Google Analytics uses), you'd have to store something in a database (BigTable on GAE) and run your own analytics.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of meaningful and derived data out of [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) instead of downloading and analyzing your log file. You may want to try with those server side stats and see if those fit your bill.